# CORS preflight returns 200 but subsequent PUT never happens (Angular JS with external REST API)

Tags: angularjs, http, nginx, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm working with an **Angular app** that talks to a **REST api**.

I have set up access-control so that my GET requests are working as expected. (The browser sends a preflight OPTIONS request and then the subsequent GET fires).

However, I am running into problems with my PUTs.

**The problem** is that with PUTs the options preflight seems to return okay but then the PUT never fires.

First I will show what works and then what is failing. I am using Charles to spy on the calls.

---

## GET (working)

1) preflight request

```
OPTIONS /v1/account HTTP/1.1
Host    api.mysite.com
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
Origin  http://127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers  accept, authorization
Accept  */*
Referer http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
```

2) preflight response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  nginx/1.6.0
Date    Wed, 21 May 2014 15:43:25 GMT
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Content-Length  0
Connection  keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, WWW-Authenticate, X-BLURR-DEBUG
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
```

3) The GET request

```
GET /v1/account HTTP/1.1
Host    api.mysite.com
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin  http://127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
AUTHORIZATION   DFHD8D...
Referer http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
```

4) The GET response

```
{ some json as expected }
```

---

## PUT (not working)

Now, here is the **PUT** that seems to return an okay preflight response but never gets to the PUT request:

1) preflight request

```
OPTIONS /v1/account HTTP/1.1
Host    api.mysite.com
Access-Control-Request-Method   PUT
Origin  http://127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers  accept, authorization, content-type
Accept  */*
Referer http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
```

2) preflight response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  nginx/1.6.0
Date    Wed, 21 May 2014 15:51:41 GMT
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Content-Length  0
Connection  keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, WWW-Authenticate, X-BLURR-DEBUG
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
```

---

## The problem

It seems that the **preflight** response for the PUT is okay, so I'm not sure why the browser never sends the **actual** PUT request.

Any help or direction would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The * (star) is not a valid value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header. You need to list the actual methods (e.g. `GET, PUT`). It seems like although the preflight response is successful from the server, the browser is probably still rejecting the preflight and not sending the actual request. Check the browser's console log for any errors.